# How to select a part of a string in a set, but not the string exactly in RegEx

Tags: regex

I am trying to select part of a URL **/example/privacy-policy**  and **/example/123/privacy-policy** but not **/privacy-policy**

I currently have this  `^[^\/privacy\-policy].\/privacy\-policy.$`

But it seems to not work still. Ideally, it would be able to find **privacy-policy** anywhere in the string without directly matching the root **/privacy-policy**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want `privacy-policy` as the root of your url, but you still want to match it, you can force the regex to look for at least one more symbol before the backslash that preceeds `privacy-policy`:

```
(.+\/)privacy-policy
```

Then if you want to get the part that comes before `privacy-policy`, you can reference Group 1.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: So I do need it to not match /privacy-policy as well. The other characters always come before it though. So I want it to match /example/privacy-policy but not /privacy-policy , sorry if my wording was off

Comment: No worries at all about your wordings, they were absolutely fine. I've tried this regex on https://regex101.com. Take a look here: https://imgur.com/qZTYUko, does it match what you meant to match? @lowbudget

Answer (score 2):

`^.*(?=\/privacy-policy)`

This matches everything (`.*`) from the beginning of the string (`^`) up until the string `/privacy-policy` appears. (This is called a `positive lookahead`)

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to match *privacy-policy* at the end of the string, but not
when is it */privacy-policy* at the start of the string and using a lookbehind assertion is supported:

```
(?<!^\/)\bprivacy-policy$
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!^\/)` Negative lookbehind, assert not the start of the string followed by `/` directly to the left
- `\bprivacy-policy` Match literally preceded by a word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h3i50E/1).